# make buttons with loop and set their onclick function reverse their background colors

Tags: javascript

```
function beggining1(){
        for (var i=1;i<4;i++){
            for (var j=1;j<4;j++){
                var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
                btn.className = "button1";
                btn.id = i +""+ j;

                btn.onclick = reserve(i,j);             
                var t = document.createTextNode(i+"_"+j);
                btn.appendChild(t);             
                document.getElementById("div1").appendChild(btn);

            }
            document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML += '<br>';
        }
    }
```

Ok so this function makes buttons  3x3 in square(3 rows 3 columns) but now i want to call a function when they are clicked.And i tried something like this but it does not work.So i want each time a button is clicked it turns its color from red to green / from green to red

```
function reserve(var i,var j){

        if (document.getElementById('i'+'j').style.bgColor == green){
            document.getElementById('i'+'j').style.bgColor = red;
        }
        else if (document.getElementById('i'+'j').style.bgColor == red){
            document.getElementById('i'+'j').style.bgColor == green;
        }


    }
```

Comment: getElement('i'+'j') ? are you sure about that?

Comment: You have quotes in literally all the wrong places in your `reserve` function... Also, just `btn.onclick = reserve;` will work, because you can do `if( this.stuff)` - but be aware that the browser will interpret the `green` value to `rgb(0,128,0)` or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest delegating the function to the parent element:

```
function reserve(e){
// the 'e' argument is supplied automatically (though not in IE)
    // 'e.target' is the element that was clicked, we're storing a reference
    // to avoid having to look it up again
    var el = e.target;

    // checking that a 'button' element was clicked:
    if (el.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'button') {
        // setting the backgroundColor of the clicked element, using a conditional
        // operator ('ternary') format; if the backgroundColor is currently 'green'
        // it's then set to 'red', if it's *not* 'green' it's set to 'green':
        el.style.backgroundColor = el.style.backgroundColor === 'green' ? 'red' : 'green';
    }
}

// defining the event-handler of the 'div1' element, which calls the reserve
// function:
document.getElementById('div1').addEventListener('click', reserve);
```

Note that there's no guarantee that the `'red'` or `'green'` colour-names will be preserved in the `style` object; and may be set/returned as hexadecimal, `rgba()` or, less commonly, `hsl()` colour values.

Note that, in your function, you have a few errors:

```
function reserve(var i,var j){
//               ^-- you can just declare i and j: reserve(i,v),
//                   without the var declaration
    if (document.getElementById('i'+'j').style.bgColor == green){
        //                       ^---^ gives the literal string 'ij',
        //                             whereas you want the sum of the numbers;
        //                             so don't quote them.
        document.getElementById('i'+'j').style.bgColor = red;
        //                                     ^-- you're looking for 
        //   style.backgroundColor
        //   the bgColor attribute is now 'legacy' (though not officially deprecated).
    }
    else if (document.getElementById('i'+'j').style.bgColor == red){
        document.getElementById('i'+'j').style.bgColor == green;
    }
}


}
```

Comment: well i thought that i need the id of the button so the function reverse the color of the button i click i dont want to sum the numbers just use them to get the id

Comment: Yes, I gathered that: but it's still wrong. Also, numeric `id`s are allowed in HTML5, but they can still cause problems in CSS and, *I think*, in JavaScript. Regardless, the delegated function *should* work and avoids the requirement of using the `id`.

Comment: but can you explain more detailed what to rework cuz its unclear to me

Comment: well if i change my "reserve" function to your "reserve" function and add the script `document.getElementById('div1').addEventListener('click' , reserve);`

I get my div changing colors when clicked

Comment: Ah, well I've added a check for that (to ensure that a `button` element is clicked, and not the `div` (or any other) element.

Comment: Everything works now i even added a confirmation for it ,but i have one last question. The function works properly but im trying to understand why the first time i click the button it stays green just the first time. By the way I call the "beggining1" function on window.onload

Comment: Because the `color` is set with CSS, maybe; you can change the condition of the ternary operator to: `e.style.backgroundColor && el.style.backgroundColor === 'green'` (which should work in most browsers, but does require that the colour is initially set to 'green' (*and* that `'green'` is the value returned by the browser). You could also, *maybe* use `window.getComputedStyle(el,null).backgroundColor == 'green'`, but this is *far* less likely to work, since `green` is unlikely to be the returned value.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use `var` when declaring functions arguments. Just write the names and will be fine:
`function reserve(i, j)`.

Also you don't want to fire `reserve` when creating the buttons which will actually happen when you write: `btn.onclick = reserve(i,j);`
This will evaluate `reserve` with current `i` and `j` and assign the *return value* of `resverve` as on click handler. Just write the function name without any brackets: `btn.onclick = reserve`

Further

```
document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML += '<br>';
```

seems to overwrite already assigned event handlers. Read: Clicking on the button does not result in `reserved` being called. I assume `+=` will some Browser (Chromium in my case) take the current HTML as a String, append the new String and write it back - loosing additional information for the elements.
A better approach would be

```
document.getElementById('div1').appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
```

And finally I would rewrite `reserve` as following:

```
function reserve(event) {
    var clickedButton = event.target;
    //console.log(clickedButton.style.backgroundColor);
    //console.log(window.getComputedStyle(clickedButton).backgroundColor);
    if (clickedButton.style.backgroundColor == "green") {
        clickedButton.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    } else {
        clickedButton.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }
}
```

`event` is an argument passed to your `onclick` handler by the browser and `event.target` will hold a reference to the clicked element. (Use `console.log(event)` to see what other information you could consider).
Then it's `style.backgroundColor` and for the sake of demonstration I made the `else if` an `else` because otherwise nothing would happen (I haven't assigned any background color by default).

Edit: Awww - David was much faster than me ;_;

Comment: im assigning background color from CSS and this makes a problem the first time i click it does not change

Comment: @Arch_interpreter You may want to comment out the console.logs I've just added to `reserve` you'll see that for first click style.backgroundColor is empty but via `getComputedStyle` you will get a rgb() value - so you might want to change the if else accordingly.

Comment: I've fiddled around and came up with this: http://jsfiddle.net/VfVCt/ However this works in Chromium and FF but different browser might translate e.g. "green" to different values => No cross browser guarantee unless you use e.g. hexadezimal values but then again it also depends on the return value of `window.getComputedStyle` …